# Чи є різниця між словами "паркан", "огорожа", "загорожа", "тин" та "штахети"

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Всі ці слова бачимо в СУМі:

[**Паркан**](http://sum.in.ua/s/parkan):

> Стіна, звичайно дерев'яна, що обгороджує або відгороджує що-небудь;
>   **огорожа**.

[**Огорожа/Огорода**](http://sum.in.ua/s/oghorozha):

> **Паркан**, стіна, тин і т. ін., які оточують що-небудь.

[**Загорожа**](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghorozha):

> **Тин**, **паркан**, стіна і т. ін., чим огороджене, відгороджене що-небудь;
>   **огорожа**.

[**Тин**](http://sum.in.ua/s/tyn):

> **Огорожа**, сплетена з лози, тонкого гілля пліт.
>   **Огорожа** з очерету тощо.
>
> **Огорожа** з жердин, покладених горизонтально й закріплених між
>   стовпцями.

[**Штахети**](http://sum.in.ua/s/shtakhety):

> **Загорожа** з дерев'яних дощечок або металевих прутів.

Як бачимо в самому СУМі в усіх словах є такі моменти, коли можна зробити висновок, що все це синоніми "огорожа - це паркан", "тин - це огорожа" тощо. Також деякі із них навіть зустрічають в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD) (а ось тут синоніми до слова "[штахети](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)").

Однак, особисто мені здається, що паркан не обов'язково має пути високим, а от загорожа чи огорожа повинні повністю закривати ділянку навколо якої вони побудовані, а, наприклад, тин - це більше декоративний елемент.

Вдалося знайти ось цю [статтю](http://montagnik.com/bydivnuztvo/2328-parkan-i-ogoroga.html), де вказується, що є відміності між парканом і огорожею, однак, чи є якісь ще джерела чи інформація, яка б чітко розмежувала ці слова. Чи, можливо, деякі із них все ж таки є синонімами?

Answer (score 1):

Так, різниця є. Ці слова мають різні корені, різне етимологічне походження. А разом з цим і мають свої особливості.

Інколи важко знайти щось в тлумачному словнику. А якщо навіть і знаходиш, то через відсутність достатньої компетенції слова можуть бути недостатньо, неточно або взагалі хибно розтлумачені.

Огорожа та загорожа явно мають спільний корінь. Префікси вказують на особливості використання. Якщо в огорожі явно вказано городження навколо чогось, то в загороді - значення кола вже відсутнє.

Дуже добре різницю між словами можна побачити в пошуку через Ґуґл світлин. Можна зрозуміти, що паркан та огорожа - це те саме. А ось різниця між огорожею, тином та паркетом вже видна чіткіше.

На основі пошуку можна сказати:

- тин - це огорожа з дерев'яних довгих гнучких гілок живих чи неживих,
- паркан - це огорожа набагато сучасніша і може мати різного роду матеріали від суцільно металу до складних конструкцій,
- штахети - це огорожа з вертикальних штахетин переважно дерев'яних, бо інших я не зустрічав.

І так, усе це можна віднести до огорожі.

Comment: Будь ласка, обґрунтовуйте дописи посиланнями на поважні джерела. Дописи без обґрунтувань викликають заперечення, довгі обговорення і мінуси.

Comment: @BeBraveBeLikeUkraine Будь ласка, доведіть, що вказане мною можна знайти в джерелах, яким можна довіряти.

Comment: Насправді, це так не працює. Не треба перекладати [*onus probandi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof_(philosophy)) на ваших читачів. Якщо ж, натомість, ви вважаєте, що не існує відповіді у тому вигляді, як того вимагають правила Stack Exchange, тобто, *об'єктивно-обґрунтованої і підкріпленої поважними джерелами*, то ваш допис має містити саме це, а не починатися зі слів «різниця є».

Comment: Перепишіть. ... і ще 5 якихось символів, щоб можна було вставити це перше слово.

Answer (score -2):

На рахунок, штахет, то це зовсім інше слово, бо штахети то просто купа штахет (або *штахетин*, *штахеток*). Одна штахета, друга штахета, ..., і так далі. http://sum.in.ua/s/shtakhetka

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3966)